# Problems to use csv: to-file in NetLogo 6.2

Tags: netlogo

I have a question about using the csv extension in NetLogo. I would like to export a .csv file using the csv extension. However, my output is per tick and when using csv: to-file it only writes the last tick. It's like csv:to-file would delete previous ticks. I looked for ways not to delete and couldn't find a solution. Does anyone know if it is possible to use csv: to-file per tick, without erasing previous ticks? I need to use csv because I am working with lists. OBS.: It is not possible to accumulate the values ​​generated at each iteration, because the list would be large and ended up having a memory problem

Thanks in advance

Below is a code showing that csv: to-file deletes the previous information (only the values ​​5,6 and 7,8 appear in the file)

```
to test
csv:to-file (" test-1.csv" ) [ [1 2] [ 3 4 ] ]
csv:to-file (" test-1.csv" ) [ [5 6] [ 7 8 ] ]
end
```

Comment: Check out the answer on netlogo-users.

Answer (score 1):

yes, csv:to-file is for writing a whole file at a time. To write one line each tick, you need csv:to-row, which converts a list to a line of csv output:

```
file-open "The-file-name.csv"
file-print csv:to-row (list output-1 output-2 output-3 ...)
file-close
```

(This is quite fast and will not slow your code down unless your model is extremely simple. Unfortunately there is not an example of it in the Models Library's csv code example.)

Comment: Hi Charles and Steve Railsback, thanks for the help and response. Resolved! :)